# segmentation fault in C by replacing a string's letter

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, cs50

I want to replace a character (for example the second one) from a string.
What's wrong with my code? It can compile, but instead of doing what I need it give me a Segmentation fault. Thanks!

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    string key="abcd";
    key[1]='f';
}
```

And after compiled my code

```
~/workspace/pset2/crack/ $ clang -ggdb3 -O0 -std=c11 -Wall -Werror -Wshadow bug.c -lcrypt -lcs50 -lm -o bug
~/workspace/pset2/crack/ $ ./bug
Segmentation fault
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only modify memory that is in the heap or stack, your `"abcd"` there is what is known as a String Literal and belongs in the program's read-only memory space, it cannot be modified where it is (not if it's running under any decent operational system anyway).

The reason it's placed there to begin with is because `string` is basically just a `char *` pointer, and it will point to any memory space and doesn't care if it's in read-only space or not. (not to be confused with C++ `std::string`).

To make it modifiable you have to tell C it's not a pointer, but an array.

```
char key[] = "abcd";
```

Now C will place this string in the stack where you can modify it at will.

Answer (score 0):

```
string key="abcd";
```

`string` is basically `char *` ,`key` is  string literal. You try to modify it, therefore the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see the definition of name `string` but I think it is something like `char *`.

Thus in this declaration

```
 string key="abcd";
```

there is declared a pointer to a string literal.

String literals are unmodified in C, Any attempt to modify a string literal results in undefined behavior.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: `string` is a typedef from a library called `cs50`, and you got it right -- it's only `char*`. Apparently this library is used in Harvard introductory courses to read from the keyboard. It sounds useful, but this typedef really shouldn't exist.

Comment: @giusti Thanks for the information.:)

Answer (score 0):

This is because `"abcd"` is not really copied into your `key` variable.
Instead, `key` is a pointer to this constant string.

If you want to be able to modify it, you can do this :

```
int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    char key[] = { "some string" };
    key[1]='f';
}
```